# Conditional sapply in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to apply conditional sapply to vectors as shown below
Basically, then the vector contains "input_" in the beginning, then apply some condition to LHS and RHS.

The condition is when there is "input_b", then RHS should be `paste0(x, "d")`, where LHS should be `gsub("input_", "", x)`. Here RHS is working fine but not the LHS part. Refer expected output below

```
exp <- c("a", "input_b")
asd <- as.list(sapply(exp , function(x) {ifelse(substr(x, start = 0, stop = 5) == "input", assign(gsub("input_", "", x), paste0(x, "d")), assign(x, x))}))
asd
$a
[1] "a"

$input_b
[1] "input_bd"
```

Expected output

```
asd
$a
[1] "a"

$b
[1] "input_bd"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setNames` instead of `assign` (`sapply` seems redundant, because `exp` is not a list):

```
exp_values <- ifelse(startsWith(exp, "input"),
                     paste0(exp, "d"),
                     exp)

exp_names <- ifelse(startsWith(exp, "input"),
                    gsub("input_", "", exp),
                    exp)

as.list(setNames(exp_values, exp_names))
```

Output:

```
$a
[1] "a"

$b
[1] "input_bd"
```

It is however still not clear to me what problem we're solving exactly, so it might not be the most efficient way to solve the problem at hand.